# How to bulk edit SSIS project with hundreds of rowversion columns

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with an orphaned index, so I'm thinking I need to create a new database and move all the objects over to it.

I've scripted the creation of all the tables and stored procedures, etc, and now I'm to the point to move the data. There are roughly 8000 tables, so I've used the Export Data Wizard to create four SSIS packages (transferring about 2k tables each).

My problem is that many of the tables contain a `rowversion` column, which causes errors when I open the projects in BIDS. If the problem field has the same name in every table, is there some way that I can do a bulk edit so the project ignores any column with this name? Or am I left with having to manually edit every table with an error in the project? Also, if there's a more efficient way to do this, I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can definitely do this bulk editing with the API but I'm not clear on what "ignore any field with this name" means.

Comment: In my projects, all the fields of type rowversion that are throwing errors have the same name. So I would want to change those fields to a status of "ignore" instead of trying to send their values to the destination database. Still thinking the API is my best bet?

Answer (score 0):

I should mention at the start that directly editing your .dtsx file can easily corrupt the SSIS package.

The four SSIS packages should each have a .dtsx file. It is technically feasible to open the .dtsx in a text editor. Maybe this can work?

1) Create a copy of your SSIS packages

2) Using BIDS, open one package and make one change

3) Look at the before and after images of your package

If you are lucky, perhaps a simple find and replace all can solve it. For a text editor, I recommend [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

[This post gives advice on editing .dtsx file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/08230caf-b1d5-411d-8532-b89b30ce5b6f/is-there-a-safe-way-to-edit-dtsx-files-directly-)